# Disable crypto padding

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api

If I use this code:

```
let enc = new TextEncoder();
let data = enc.encode('January February');

let algorithm = {
   name: 'AES-CBC', iv: enc.encode('0123456789ABCDEF')
};

crypto.subtle.importKey(
   'raw', enc.encode('GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV'), 'AES-CBC', true, ['encrypt']
).then(
   key => crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, data)
).then(
   ct => console.log(btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(ct))))
);
```

I get this result:

```
q6BAetimbeLcdlSC7GoBbtrh/HM4xs3t1+BzEYxdEIk=
```

If I use this PHP code, I get the same result:

```
echo openssl_encrypt(
   'January February', 'aes-128-cbc', 'GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV', iv: '0123456789ABCDEF'
);
```

However PHP has the option to disable padding:

```
echo openssl_encrypt(
   'January February',
   'aes-128-cbc',
   'GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV',
   OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,
   '0123456789ABCDEF'
);
```

Result:

```
q6BAetimbeLcdlSC7GoBbg==
```

Can padding be disabled with JavaScript? If not, what is a good way to get the
same shorter output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebCrypto uses in the context of AES-CBC [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) by default ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54746103/9014097)), which as far as I know cannot be disabled (s. also the documentation of [`SubtleCrypto.encrypt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt)).

Encryption with AES-CBC without padding is only possible if the plaintext is an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES), as in your example. In this case PKCS7 appends a complete block with padding bytes (which are all 0x10), i.e. in the ciphertext only this last block needs to be removed:

```
//
// Your code (implicit base64 encoding)
//
$enc = openssl_encrypt('January February', 'aes-128-cbc', 'GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV', OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, '0123456789ABCDEF');
print($enc . PHP_EOL);

//
// Remove last block (explicit Base64 encoding required, since the last block of the ACTUAL ciphertext must be removed)
//
$enc = base64_encode(substr(openssl_encrypt('January February', 'aes-128-cbc', 'GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, '0123456789ABCDEF'), 0, -16));
print($enc . PHP_EOL);
```

and

```js
let enc = new TextEncoder();
let data = enc.encode('January February');

let algorithm = {
   name: 'AES-CBC', iv: enc.encode('0123456789ABCDEF')
};

crypto.subtle.importKey(
   'raw', enc.encode('GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV'), 'AES-CBC', true, ['encrypt']
).then(
   key => crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, data)
).then(     
   ct => console.log(btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(ct).slice(0, -16)))) // reomve last block
);
```

Both code snippets provide `q6BAetimbeLcdlSC7GoBbg==` as output.

It should be noted, that decryption is more expensive because the *encrypted* padding bytes must be added (if there is no valid PKCS7 padding after decryption, a `DOMException` is thrown).

---

There are of course JavaScript libraries that are more comfortable than the low level WebCrypto API, and that also support different paddings as well as disabling padding, e.g. [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding):

```js
var data = 'January February';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('0123456789ABCDEF');

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    data, 
    key,
    {
        iv: iv,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
    }
);

console.log(encrypted.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer is great, but as an alternative, you can use the builtin Node
`crypto` API:

```js
let crypto = require('crypto');
let [pt, key, iv] = ['January February', 'GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV', '0123456789ABCDEF'];
// default is padding, omit last method if needed
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv).setAutoPadding(false);
let ct = cipher.update(pt, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
console.log(ct);
```

and here is an example using the Deno `crypto` library:

```js
import { Aes } from 'http://deno.land/x/crypto/aes.ts';
import { Cbc, Padding } from 'http://deno.land/x/crypto/block-modes.ts';
let te = new TextEncoder;

let [pt, key, iv] = [
   te.encode('January February'),
   te.encode('GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV'),
   te.encode('0123456789ABCDEF')
];

// default is no padding, omit last argument if needed
let cipher = new Cbc(Aes, key, iv, Padding.PKCS7);
let ct = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...cipher.encrypt(pt)));
console.log(ct);
```

- https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html
- https://deno.land/x/crypto